# Oracle : Getting Notification when table gets new data's

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

In psql we have PL/Perl to communicate with external program when the new row is inserted into our table. Like that is there any way (procedural language ) to communicate with external program in Oracle . For achieving this things, what should I do.....?

Can any one help me out of this problem.....

Comment: why down vote's................?

Comment: Don't Know but I must say that thank you to your question I have learnt about the Change Notification feature.

Comment: I downvoted. There's no suggestion whether this external program runs on the database server, an app server, somewhere else, or whether you 'communicate' to it through a network port, web service, parameter, or whether it should fire when the data is inserted or when that insert is committed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle offeres packages to communicate externally to a file, or pipe.  Create a trigger to write to one of these when a row is updated.  Be careful how you deal with failures in this code so you don't lock up the database or rollback the transaction if you external program is not available. Checkout out the utl packages.

Answer (score 3):

The *most suitable* answer to your rather vague question depends on the kind of problem you want to solve when you mention *communicate with external programs*.

Answer (score 2):

Please check documentation about Oracle's Database Change Notification, you will find your answers there.